# OS X bash - make Shift-TAB work to reverse cycle possible matches

Tags: bash

The answer here is great: [Is there a way to make bash more TAB friendly?](https://superuser.com/questions/59175/is-there-a-way-to-make-bash-more-tab-friendly)

But is there any way to make Shift-TAB key work as well - so it does work in reversed direction?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've found the answer here: http://brettterpstra.com/2011/09/25/quick-tip-some-inputrc-fun/

The solution is to add following line to `.inputrc` file in home folder:

```
"\e[Z": "\e-1\C-i"
```

Although I have absolutely no idea how it works. :-)

Comment: basically it works by linking one shortcut key (shift tab) to another one built into the bash